# raw_input stops GUI from appearing

Tags: python, tkinter, raw-input

I have written a program in Python that allow me to change the names of many files all at once. I have one issue that is quite odd.

When I use raw_input to get my desired extension, the GUI will not launch. I don't get any errors, but the window will never appear.

I tried using raw_input as a way of getting a file extension from the user to build the file list. This program will works correctly when raw_input is not used.The section of code that I am referring to is in my globList function. For some reason when raw_imput is used the window will not launch.

```
import os
import Tkinter
import glob
from Tkinter import *

def changeNames(dynamic_entry_list, filelist):
    for index in range(len(dynamic_entry_list)):
        if(dynamic_entry_list[index].get() != filelist[index]):
            os.rename(filelist[index], dynamic_entry_list[index].get())

    print "The files have been updated!" 



def drawWindow(filelist):

    dynamic_entry_list = []
    my_row = 0
    my_column = 0
    for name in filelist:
        my_column = 0
        label = Tkinter.Label(window, text = name, justify = RIGHT)
        label.grid(row = my_row, column = my_column)

        my_column = 1
        entry = Entry(window, width = 50)
        dynamic_entry_list.append(entry)
        entry.insert(0, name)
        entry.grid(row = my_row, column = my_column)

        my_row += 1       
    return dynamic_entry_list


def globList(filelist):
    #ext = raw_input("Enter the file extension:")
    ext = ""
    desired = '*' + ext
    for name in glob.glob(desired):
        filelist.append(name)




filelist = []
globList(filelist)
window = Tkinter.Tk()
user_input = drawWindow(filelist)
button = Button(window, text = "Change File Names", command = (lambda      e=user_input: changeNames(e, filelist)))
button.grid(row = len(filelist) + 1 , column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Is this a problem with raw_input?

What would be a good solution to the problem?

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how tkinter is defined to work. It is single threaded, so while it's waiting for user input it's truly waiting. `mainloop` must be running so that the GUI can respond to events, including internal events such as requests to draw the window on the screen.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't be mixing a GUI with reading input from stdin. If you're creating a GUI, get the input from the user via an entry widget. Or, get the user input before creating the GUI.

A decent tutorial on popup dialogs can be found on the effbot site: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm